# Schrodingers PI; dead or alive?

Tags: pi-2, hardware, power-supply, crash

last days one of my Pi2 crashed over night. At morning i realized the Pi is down (no response on network, plugged to monitor and keyboard did not give any response) I plug out/in the power supply to restart the Pi. The red and green LED are on bright and steady.

Okay first thought was a corrupt SD card, i put the card in another Pi2 and it booted without any issue. Back in the faulty Pi again both LEDs are on. I tried another SD card with a fresh downloaded Raspbian image but no changes -  no boot. Changed the power supply no changes... seems to be dead.

I was quite busy and couldn't investigate more so left the Pi without Power for 2 Days. Today i decided to throw it in the trash but before I plugged again the power and it booted. I rebooted serval times and the Pi seem not to have an issue. Now it runs since 7hrs in normal condition.

- What could be the cause of the fault?
- I backuped the SD after crash, in which logs i could find details for the crash?
- is the Pi still trustworthy for 24/7 or would it be better to replace it?

Comment: Was the Pi extremely hot?

Comment: @RonBeyer, can't tell you. The last syslog entry was at 4:15 and I noticed the outage serval hours later at 8:30. While testing the temperature normal. Now I am logging `vcgencmd measure_temp` and send mail alerts after passing a 50°C threshold. Until now the Temp is always below 45°C.

Comment: It is also possible to pop the poly fuse with too much current draw, do you have a lot of connected devices? The fuses can take anywhere from seconds to hours to reset depending on how they were triggered.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resettable_fuse We've had at least one person claim their pi was dead due to overcurrent for something like a day, they figured it was wrecked and left it in a closet, plugged it in weeks or months later and it was fine.

Comment: i used a "RASPBERRY PI UNIVERSAL POWER SUPPLY" for the Pi connected to an UPS. Power issues has been the last thing that I would have in mind. Specially since the Pi did not respond after unplug and plug the power supply. are the LEDs on the board on, if the fuse had triggered? Its a good idea to measure on the fuse the next time the Pi becomes a living dead... i'll keep this in mind.

Comment: The running joke wasthat kind of thing was called an electrical phenomenon back when I debugged computers for a living. We sometimes tried to break it with vibration in case it was mechanical and circuit cooler spray for temperature effects.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Alive.**

It was probably the polyfuse. Your shady power supply might have tripped it, unless it was from a reputable source.

Other than that, an accessory might have pulled too much power from the Pi, blowing the polyfuse.

---

For past logs, you can check out `/var/log/kern.log` if you're on Raspbian.

---

Yes, it may still be trustworthy. I would't worry about it. Just check your accessories if they draw too much power.

If, for example, you have 4 external HDDs attached, you may want to get a powered hub.